# MySQL database Query, searching for something not in a database

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to do something I am not sure is possible and I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out.

I have a table currently lined up like this:

request_id |  module_code | room_assigned | year | week | day | start_period | duration

What I am trying to do is query the table above for a room_assigned where it does not equal a result in the table of a year, week, day, start_period, duration.

I have a table with all the rooms that may exists.

I am trying to find a room not assigned to the time period.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: It seems like you wouldn't only want to check for a match on those five columns, but also that the room does not exist in the other table for a duration

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how the values are entered.  If you need to query for availability, you need the have the end period calculated from your duration so you you could do find occupied rooms with:

SELECT secondtable.room FROM firsttable RIGHT JOIN secondtable ON firsttable.room_assigned = secondtable.rooms WHERE $time_period > firsttable.start_period AND $time_period < $endperiodcaculated

You could then use code to return values from the second table not in the results.  Or, use SELECT INTO to create a temporary table, and query for values with ...WHERE secondtable.room NOT IN ($valuesfromtemp)